# Unable to get Sentry to log issues with React locally

Tags: reactjs, sentry

New to Sentry and trying to get it setup for the first time in my local dev environment. I am following the Install and Configure instructions but nothing is being logged in the Sentry dashboard. An error is being thrown in the browser but nothing is being sent to Sentry. What am I doing wrong?

React version 16.12.0

index.js

```
const Index = () => {
...
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/react";
import { Integrations } from "@sentry/tracing";
import App from './App';

Sentry.init({
    dsn: "https://#####@####.ingest.sentry.io/####",
    integrations: [new Integrations.BrowserTracing()],
    tracesSampleRate: 1.0,
});
return (
<BrowserRouter history={history}>
    <UserContext.Provider value={providerValue}>
        <App />
    </UserContext.Provider>
</BrowserRouter>
);
}
ReactDOM.render(<Index />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Intentional error

```
return <button onClick={methodDoesNotExist}>Break the world</button>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot expect your users to whitelist your app in their AdBlockers. You need to have some kind of tunnel here.

```js
Sentry.init({
  dns: 'yourDNS',
  tunnel: '/tunnel'
})
```

as suggested here in https://github.com/getsentry/examples/blob/master/tunneling/nextjs/pages/api/tunnel.js

Answer (score -1):

Turns out [uBlock Origin](https://ublockorigin.com/) was blocking Sentry's API call. I was able to figure this out by looking at the Browser's console, Network tab and seeing that the call to sentry.io had an error. Upon closer inspection of the Transferred column, it showed that it was blocked by uBlock Origin.

Turning uBlock Origin off got it working.

[image]

Comment: You might consider deleting your question then.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @U.Windl, why delete it? Somebody else might have the same issue.